# Simple SQL statement taking too long

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, sql-order-by

I got a table with around 900k records
`votes` is an INT field has numbers between NULL-500k
`rating` is Decimal between 0.0 and 10.0

These queries take around 3 seconds

```
select * from movie where genre = 'action' order by rating asc limit 0,2000; 
select * from movie where genre = 'action' order by votes asc limit 0,2000;
```

this one never finishes

```
select * from movie where genre ='action' order by votes desc limit 0,2000;
```

I tried adding an index on votes and it makes no difference

I am puzzled why it's having so much problems sorting an int field. Any ideas why?

Comment: where did you put the index ? should be on `genre`

Comment: can you show me the results of `SHOW CREATE TABLE movies;` Also, can you show me the results of `EXPLAIN EXTENDED select * from movie where genre = 'action' order by rating asc limit 0,2000; `

Answer (score 0):

- Create two compound indexes on this table to see if you can boost performance. One should be on `(genre, rating)`, and the other should be on `(genre, votes)`. These compound indexes will help handle the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses efficiently for the queries you've shown.
- Try this query to see if things get faster:

  `select * 
     from movie
    where genre='action'
      and votes is not null
    order by votes desc
    limit 2000`

  This will get rid of your NULL votes which could be confounding your query.
- Don't use `select *` ; you may be able to get faster results if you only fetch the columns you need.
- Redefine your `votes` column so it's `NOT NULL`, and make the default value zero.  NULL values don't work very efficiently in `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` clauses.